# Brightness control not working for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, brightness

When pressing brightness control buttons on my laptop, there is no change in brightness. Brightness is set at a very high level and it hurts the eyes. Provide some solution ASAP.

Comment: what's the output of `lspci` and `ls /sys/class/backlight/`

Comment: does it start working if you run `gnome-settings-daemon` in terminal ?

Comment: @Ron 'lspci' gives a lot of lines as output and 'ls /sys/class/backlight/' gives 'acpi_video0' as output. And i have AMD board.

Comment: None of the answers worked and i ended up removing Ubuntu from my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an intel controller in `/sys/class/backlight`, then create a file by:

`sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

and copy the following code into it, then save and exit:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "card0"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
        BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Reboot and see if solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your kernel.. I have a relatively recent ultrabook and every distribution based on Ubuntu 14.10 and other  previous versions fails to work properly with Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and graphics, specifically the brightness options. 
On the other hand, since the update to 15.04, the new available kernel is 3.19..... This one includes all the hotkeys of the more recent pc's, and works perfectly with all of the hardware.

You shouldn't really update kernel unless something is really wrong. Sadly this is the case... Follow this page to update your kernel:

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/linux-kernel-3-19-3-released-install-update-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-other-debian-based-distros

After that, just reboot and it should be just fine!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

System settings > Brightness & Lock -->adjust your brightness