# At login, brightness goes to minimum, fastly goes back to maximum and didn't change anymore

Tags: brightness, intel

I updated my ubuntu to 15:04 , but after que I can no longer reduce brightness. Even when I try with FN keys, the indicator varies, but the brightness doesn't change.

I've tried many ways to change the brightness, but nothing works. Seems like the video drivers doesn't response to command.

**It may be helpful:**

```
~$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
intel_backlight
```

**20-intel.conf:**

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

**About my laptop:**

```
~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core
processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Holco Enterprise Co, Ltd/Shuttle Computer Device 2032
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

**Graphics:** Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
**Model**: Positivo Unique S1991i

Comment: please edit and add output of `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Comment: The file opened is empty.

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/228816/i-cannot-change-the-screen-brightness) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104162/decrease-backlight-below-minimum)

Comment: I've saw this, but the file is empty. Can build this file or something like this?

Comment: Try [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)  but I'm not sure! and [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/) may help!

Comment: The first one i've tried doesn't works. And the app, the Ubuntu Software Center can't find, maybe because my ubuntu is 15.04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28921/discussion-between-ravan-and-jluann).

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/618231/brightness-control-not-working-for-ubuntu-14-04/618240#618240

Comment: I've tried this and still isn't working

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. And also specify your laptop model.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/476664 I think this might be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

The editor will open. Post there this text

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Save the file and reboot.

Comment: I've tried this already. It doesn't work too.

Comment: And what is your laptop?